# How to transform Unity terrain coordinates

Tags: c#, unity, vector

My map creator created some terrain in Unity, but all my scripts are based on the X-Y axis. Is there an easy and smart way to transform them into Z-Y, or do I have to change all the vector variables to Vector3 and move the coordinates to (0,Y,Z)?

Comment: What format is the map in?

Comment: It's a Scene, its not modeled.

Comment: He made it using terrain but you cant rotate terrain in unity that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Unity's terrain, you'll have to make some sacrifices. Unity's terrain is semi-procedural and stuck in the Z-Y plane, so you'll either have to:

- export the terrain data and import it into a third party terrain generator (I think Blender has a plugin for that) and then repaint the textures onto it.
- or change the scripts around to be in "top down" form.
- find something on the store that mimics Unity's terrain generator and supports what you need.

Comment: Can you propose an other way for creating terrains?

Comment: That depends on what you want to accomplish. It's possible to make terrain using any modelling program that supports sculpting, like Mudbox, ZBrush, or Blender. Blender at least is free, and I recommend it for low-poly terrain, although there is a bit of a learning curve. There are also a bunch of purpose built applications too, like World Machine, Geocontrol, and Terrain Composer. As far as I know, all of them can either import height maps out of the box, or with a plugin.

Comment: Before you mentioned terrains format can that be a problem with the colliders ?

Comment: It can be - you'd want to use a mesh collider along with whatever kind of terrain you decided on. Unity's terrain is purpose built to handle that, and likely has several optimizations with terrain in mind (hence the fixed axis).

Comment: There's a paper on terrain systems like that here: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131841/continuous_lod_terrain_meshing_.php